How do I calculate atomic displacements after relaxation?
I have relaxed a 64-atom structure and would like to calculate the min/mean/max displacements relative to a defect center at the origin. In principle this is simple, but I am confused about how to deal with the periodic boundary conditions (PBC) in my unit cell. I am using Python to run all my calculations and would greatly appreciate any guidance on how to undo the PBCs before determining the displacements.

If you have the input/output files, just compare the atoms inside the unit cells. Something like $\Delta x_1 = x_{1(output)} - x_{1(input)}$ for atom 1 and X coordinate, etc. Or you can calculate the RMSD value for the whole cell.

What if the displacement magnitude is larger than half the lattice of the unit cell? Doesn't there need to be some sort of a minimum image distance convention enforced in the calculations?

Well, as you have PBC, if an atom "fly-away" from one side of your unit cell with such big displacement, it will "appear" at the other side.

If it appears on the other side, it will appear to have jumped discontinuously by a lattice constant... I have had to handle this situation before for MD trajectories. Solution: calculate the displacement at every step relative to the 0th step and, if at any given step the distance jumps by more than half a box vector, apply minimum image convention. This way, the displacements vary smoothly over time
